# What is wrong with this bootstrap 5.2 tab html?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am really busting my head here. Trying to make bootstrap tabs working.
Example works, but when I try to generate my own tabs like this, they don't work. I must be missing something very stupid:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-run-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-0-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-0-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-0-pane" aria-selected="true">0
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="802a6e18-485b-4cfe-8154-d67b677a565f-1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#802a6e18-485b-4cfe-8154-d67b677a565f-1-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="802a6e18-485b-4cfe-8154-d67b677a565f-1-pane" aria-selected="false">1
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="0dc3ed87-6c4e-496a-a313-c2b6d606d8ad-2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#0dc3ed87-6c4e-496a-a313-c2b6d606d8ad-2-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="0dc3ed87-6c4e-496a-a313-c2b6d606d8ad-2-pane" aria-selected="false">2
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="852d36ac-2768-48ac-9fa4-e73d1459b780-3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#852d36ac-2768-48ac-9fa4-e73d1459b780-3-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="852d36ac-2768-48ac-9fa4-e73d1459b780-3-pane" aria-selected="false">3
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="b7193c34-b2e8-4577-a07d-3e71acd7b1e2-4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#b7193c34-b2e8-4577-a07d-3e71acd7b1e2-4-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="b7193c34-b2e8-4577-a07d-3e71acd7b1e2-4-pane" aria-selected="false">4
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-run-tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-0-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="7b310c9a-3300-483e-9ddd-6de1d38c228c-0-tab" tabindex="0">
        Content for: 0
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="802a6e18-485b-4cfe-8154-d67b677a565f-1-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="802a6e18-485b-4cfe-8154-d67b677a565f-1-tab" tabindex="0">
        Content for: 1
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="0dc3ed87-6c4e-496a-a313-c2b6d606d8ad-2-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="0dc3ed87-6c4e-496a-a313-c2b6d606d8ad-2-tab" tabindex="0">
        Content for: 2
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="852d36ac-2768-48ac-9fa4-e73d1459b780-3-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="852d36ac-2768-48ac-9fa4-e73d1459b780-3-tab" tabindex="0">
        Content for: 3
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b7193c34-b2e8-4577-a07d-3e71acd7b1e2-4-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="b7193c34-b2e8-4577-a07d-3e71acd7b1e2-4-tab" tabindex="0">
        Content for: 4
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/716qtugz/

Comment: Why do you have such cryptic ids? It seems like it just makes all of your code way more cluttered unless you need them to be this way. It would be much easier to read and find the problem if you can change them to have less characters.

Comment: Those are just IDs of my data so it was the most convenient to use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ids are invalid. Id's in HTML cannot start with a number. That's why you get an error an your code is not working.

as you can read [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-id-attribute-3468186), this is the structure of a valid Id (I quote)
Rules for Using the ID Attribute

Ensure your ID attributes conform to these three standards:

> ```
> The ID must start with a letter (a-z or A-Z).
> All subsequent characters can be letters, numbers (0-9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).
> Each ID must be unique within the document.
> ```

I see your Ids are a bit strange; maybe they are generated by some part of your program. If thats the case ensure that the id generated starts always with a letter

Here its a working example https://jsfiddle.net/0htv2wz3/ (I just took your code and changed the IDs to ones that start with letters and removed the ones that are not necessary for the example; as you see it works properly)

Comment: Dan is right... I didnt know this about ID's, I was trying to debug your question and kept getting script errors... thinking wtf! But if you prepend a letter to your programatically generated ID's and voilà it works sweet... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/4zgkmydc/1/ ...nice answer [@Daniel Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17537072/daniel-cruz) !

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something dumb and simple.